# WL.Server.notifyAllDevices need to add custom property in notification

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a little problem that I need to add custom parameter/property to the notification

```
function submitNotification(userId, notificationText){
    var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId);

    if (userSubscription==null){
        return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
    }

    var badgeDigit = 1;

    var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});

    WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText); 
    WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification); 

    return { 
        result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId 
    };
}


// need to pass custom property content-available:1 but not in payload
```

As I am currently using MobileFirst 7.1.0. The purpose of this enhancement is I need to update notification badge in iPhone App when App is in not started stage. By Adding content-available:1 at 1st level of notification can help to complete it. Any Luck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guys. Thanks for all your concerns.
Here is the answer:

```
function submitNotification(userId, notificationText){
    var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId);

    if (userSubscription==null){
        return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
    }

    var badgeDigit = 1;

    var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});
    //notification = {alert:"test in here",
    //              badge:4,
    //              payload: {custom:"data1"},
    //              "content-available":1};

    notification.APNS.type = "MIXED" ;
    notification.APNS.badge = 89;
    notification.APNS.alert = "in here";
    notification.APNS['content-available'] = 1;

    WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText); 
    WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification); 

    return { 
        result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The badge is determined by the variable that you have in your code:

```
var badgeDigit = 1;
```

Change this to another number and that's what will be displayed on the application icon when a notification arrives to the device.

Note that MobileFirst does not provide any built-in support to decrease that number for you. That means that in your application logic you will then need to use the API method `WL.Badge` to change it: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Badge.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-4

Comment: Actually the thing is, this badgeDigit works for iPhone. But my scenario is different. It's a detailed scope. I would be great Idan If I can get how can I customize notifyAllDevice parameter to send 'content-available:1' as a parameter. Right now notifyAlllDevices or createdefaultnotification function is not allowing any other parameter. How Can I add or put this customized parameter to the function ... need help Man

Comment: So why don't you mention what is your scenario?

Comment: the scenario is. I am a user using Android & iPHone App. I recieved 10 notifications. in iPhone I read 5 notifications and in Android I read 8. Now the Badge counter for both application has changed from 10 which is in iPhone it's badge=5 and in Android it's badge=2

Comment: Problem happens here when the App is been kill/quit or in not started stage. to enable the badge and show the correct unread message counter  we have to consistently handle badge counter in our application. For Android it's possible extending GCMIntentServices.java in background/active/not started stage. But for Android there isn't any delegate to listen in background when notification arrives. so by passing content-available:1 will help us enabling the badge in all the app states.

Comment: You can use the custom:data payload option in your adapter code to send any data you'd like to handle your logic in the app according to your needs.

Comment: No, cannot use payoad because content-available:1 should be at the 1st level of the json object.